# Vba loop for many sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have vba code that adds calculations for 4 sheets. I want a loop that will calculate hundreds of sheet without adding sheetname again & again in code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

   Dim TabNames As Variant, Ordinals As Variant

   TabNames = Array("4-16 - 4-22", "4-23 - 4-29", "4-30 - 5-6")
   Ordinals = Array("1st", "2nd", "3rd")

    For i = 0 To UBound(TabNames, 1)
       Range("A5").Offset(i).Value = TabNames(i)
       Range("B5").Offset(i).Value = Ordinals(i)
       Range("I5").Offset(i).Formula = "=AVERAGE('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P)"
       Range("J5").Offset(i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P,"">=""&1)"
       Range("C5").Offset(i).Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, '" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, "">301"",'" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, ""<480"")"
       Range("D5").Offset(i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P,"">""&301,'" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P,""<""&480)"
       Range("F5").Offset(i).Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, '" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, "">=1"",'" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P, ""<300"")"
       Range("G5").Offset(i).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P,"">=""&1,'" & "adt" & TabNames(i) & "'!$P:$P,""<""&300)"
    Next
    Range("E5:E7,H5:H7,K5:K7").FormulaR1C1 = "=(R2C3-R[0]C[-2])*(R1C4*R[0]C[-1])"
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How will it determine which tabs to run in the loop? Are you saying you want it to run this code against all tabs in a workbook?

Comment: yha against all tabs in a workbook.

Comment: I believe that Don's answer below will work. Please test it out and let us know. Thanks.

Comment: I found some error like: "Subscript out of range" i think i do some mistake for adding "final calculations" in  Second routine or may be an error in final  routine. did you know how to modify it.

Comment: Make sure you change "NameOfTotalsSheet" to match the name of the tab you are storing all of your output. I'm not sure what you mean about the mistake related to "final calculations".

Comment: Its give same error again. i don't what i miss in second routine to adding calculation there.

Comment: When you get the error, press Debug. What line of code is highlighted in yellow?

Comment: " Next osheet " This line highlight in yellow in second routine.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a Chart as a tab. Change "in Sheets" to "in Worksheets" and test again.

Comment: its not work. i think i would call all routine correctly, if you know how to combine all 3 routine together please do it & specially second routine where need to "add calculation".  i guess i make some mistake there.

Comment: Here is excel workbook, if you like to see it.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxhae9snw34xuwp/Sample%20Dashboard.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Change "NameOfTotalsSheet" to "Discharge Time Dashboard". You can ignore the last part about adding a button for right now. Once all code has been pasted into your workbook, save it as an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (.xlsm) file. To run the macro press Alt+F8 to open the Macro window. Select AddAllFormulas and click Run.

Comment: Please describe this comment in second routine, "  'add final calculations here. use offset to determine location  "   which parts of basic calculation code will be use

Comment: I'm guessing that's where he intends for you to add additional calculations if needed. For example, you might take the stdev, min, or max of a column. You would need to take the offset into account to know which line these totals would go on.

Comment: Now its work perfectly. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, create a routine that does what you want for one Sheet using parameters:

```
Private Sub AddTableFormulas(ByVal sName As String, ByVal nOffset As Long)
    With Sheets("NameOfTotalsSheet")
        .Range("A5").Offset(nOffset).Value = sName
        .Range("B5").Offset(nOffset).Value = getOrdinal(nOffset + 1)
        .Range("I5").Offset(nOffset).Formula = "=AVERAGE('" & "adt" & sName & "'!$P:$P)"

        'etc

    End With
End Sub

Private Function getOrdinal(ByVal nNumber As Long) As String
    Dim sNumber As String 

    sNumber = nNumber
    Select Case Right(sNumber,1)
        Case "1"
            getOrdinal = nNumber & "st"
        Case "2"
            getOrdinal = nNumber & "nd"
        Case "3"
            getOrdinal = nNumber & "rd"
        Case Else
            getOrdinal = nNumber & "th"
    End Select

End Function
```

**Second**, write a routine that does it for all Sheets that match your criteria:

```
Public Sub AddAllFormulas()
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sName As String
    Dim nOffset As Long

    For Each oSheet In Worksheets
        If Left(oSheet.Name, 3) = "adt" Then
            sName = Right(oSheet.Name, Len(oSheet.Name) - 3)
            AddTableFormulas sName, nOffset
            nOffset = nOffset + 1
        End If
    Next 'oSheet

    'add final calculations here. use offset to determine location

End Sub
```

**Finally**, call this routine from your button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    AddAllFormulas
End Sub
```

Comment: "NameOfTotalsSheet" is hardcoded because I believe the OP wants all formulas on the same sheet.

Comment: Then I would say the row on that sheet should increment with each iteration. Otherwise, you are just overwriting the data with each new sheet.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for correcting the dots after the with. I missed that in my edit.

Comment: Thank for help, but i found some error, run time error, may be i have mistake for calling all routine or add  final calculation in code. please help me to modify it.