# Excel VBA - Portable table sort

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a follow up to an prior question I put forward which involved a multi process macro that was intended to be portable. I opted to just remove the portion which was giving me fits due to not having portability between sheets or workbooks.

I started building the sort routine, I ended up removing, by recording a macro to do the sort. Then wrote routines to identify current worksheet, and the current table I was focused on. (this was to give portability between sheets.) when I inserted variables for sheet and table names that’s when the whole thing went sideways.

I ended up eliminating it from the sheet and will have the users do their own sort, but I would like to figure it out and thought that maybe someone had done it and had a code fragment that would enlighten me.

---

I've got two segments of code now that do this with only one issue.

The first half of my code captures the table name in focus into a variable.

I've also got a piece of code that reliably will sort in the manner I want. the only issue that remains is that this second section forces me to enter the text value instead of use variables. This means that the upper portion that identifies the table name of focus is useless, and I would have to create 15 separate subs, one for each worksheet/table combination.

Below is the last of the code. Each of the refrences to "Table126" needs to be replaced with my **TableName** variable.

I can't figure out how to get this to work!

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table126")
    Dim sortcolumn As Range
    Set sortcolumn = Range("Table126[LOC]")
    With tbl.Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add(Key:=sortcolumn, Order:=xlDescending, _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
      .Header = xlYes
      .Apply
    End With
```

@DocBrown  Below your prompting for ws. prepending did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the progress I have made on this. Any help appreciated. Ken...

Comment: Your question is unclear. "can't figure out how to get this to work!" is pretty vague and does not tell us where your problem is. Replacing "Table126" by a variable `TableName` is pretty straightforward, so what precisely did you try and which error message did you get? Show us the code with the variable `TableName`, how you initialized it and how you used it, then we might be able to help.

Comment: Maybe this question here [Vba loop for many sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765280/vba-loop-for-many-sheets) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @DocBrown , sorry that I was trying to keep it short. 
When i substitute in anyway TableName for the text Table126. it errors out. The way's i've tried to do this are too numerous to post here but included many variations of adjusting the "Set sortcolumn" such as changing Range("Table126[LOC]") to "Range(" & TableName & "[LOC]")" (which throws a syntax issue. Every variation resulted in dead-ends every direction. This code work when you are on Table126, but the issue is that I have 35 different tables on 35 differ sheets, I need TableName to determine that value.

Comment: @DocBrown , I checked out the VBA Loop for many sheets and didn't see anything that looked promising for what I'm trying to cook up. It would seem to be easy replacing some text with a variable but Microsoft is fighting me here. thanks Doc.

Comment: "Range(" & TableName & "[LOC]")" is clearly syntactical nonsense, and that is not Microsoft's fault. Try something like `Set sortcolumn = ws.Range(TableName & "[LOC]")`, where `TableName` is a string variable. If it still does not work, you need to post the exact code "which does not work", and the exact error message, otherwise we cannot help you here.

Comment: @DocBrown 
The 'ws.' was missing from one of my other earlier attempts. I had tried Range(TableName & "[LOC]) earlier but never dawned on me to prepend it with 'ws.'. 
Thank you... that was driving me out of my mind!

Comment: @DocBrown if you would please convert your last comment to an answer so I can accept it and give you credit?

Comment: Well, if that really turned out to be your problem (which I was not sure about) - as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
 Set sortcolumn = ws.Range(TableName & "[LOC]")
```

where `TableName` is a string variable.

If it still does not work, you need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can actually run this thing and see the same error messages you get.