# VBA for Deleting Sheets & Save As Based on Column Values

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

I need help with VBA for deleting sheets that do not have certain characters (based on cell values in a column A) and do not equal to sheet name "IWF Extract", and then saving them based on those cell values as well.

Hoping that i can loop through all of the cell values within the column A

Thank you in advance

[image]

I have this for save as loop

```
 Sub SaveAsLoop()
 Dim wkb As Workbook
 Dim mp As String, fp As String, mfn As String, en As String, strName As String
 Dim cRng As Range, c As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set cRng = Sheets("ORG").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("ORG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
 mp = "C:\Users\oey\Documents\Kris Oey\04 JAN FY24\"
 fp = "C:\Users\oey\Documents\Kris Oey\FY24\"
 mfn = "IWF - "
 en = ".xlsm"
 ws
 Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(mp & "\Projects_WA_Summary_FY24 (TEST).xlsm")
 
 For Each c In cRng
    strName = c.Value
    wkb.SaveCopyAs (fp & mfn & strName & en)

    
 Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765280/vba-loop-for-many-sheets) would be what you are looking for in terms of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate through all worksheets, maintaining a list of relevant sheets in an array (arrSht).
- Duplicate (copy) the relevant sheets to form a new workbook.
- Save the newly created workbook with the desired name.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitWorkbook()
    Dim inWB As Workbook, outWB As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, Sht As Worksheet, arrSht
    Dim cRng As Range, c As Range
    Const IWF_SHT = "IWF Extract"
    Const ORG_SHT = "ORG"
    Const SRC_FILE = "Projects_WA_Summary_FY24 (TEST).xlsm"
    Const DES_FILE = "IWF - @.xlsm"
    Const SRC_DIR = "C:\Users\oey\Documents\Kris Oey\04 JAN FY24\"
    Const DES_DIR = "C:\Users\oey\Documents\Kris Oey\FY24\"
    
    ' If the code is in SRC_FILE, and SRC_FILE is opened
    ' Set inWB = ThisWorkbook ' OR Set inWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Open SRC_FILE
    Set inWB = Workbooks.Open(SRC_DIR & SRC_FILE)
    With inWB.Sheets("ORG")
        Set cRng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For Each c In cRng.Cells
        ReDim arrSht(1 To inWB.Worksheets.Count)
        arrSht(1) = IWF_SHT
        i = 1
        For Each Sht In inWB.Worksheets
            If InStr(1, Sht.Name, c.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                arrSht(i) = Sht.Name
            End If
        Next Sht
        ReDim Preserve arrSht(1 To i)
        inWB.Sheets(arrSht).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DES_DIR & _
            Replace(DES_FILE, "@", c.Value), _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    ' inWB.Close False
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009035)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Workbook.SaveAs method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, my workbook keeps on crashing. It seems that I have to revisit the way to approach this. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I've tested the code w/o issues. You may create a new workbook for code testing. There are IWF_SHT, ORG_SHT and several data sheets in the workbook at least. If the code works well, then you have to figure out what's wrong with the workbook file.

Comment: Understood. Maybe it's the memory issue. Thank you again. Question, if i want to save it to xlsx instead, what would the FileFormat be? Thank you :)

Comment: Please try `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Comment: Thank you again for this; just to give you an updated: I believe it's a memory issue since I split the workbook into two and it's running smoothly. Thank you so much :)